# Remove substring matching pattern both in the beginning and the end of the variable

Tags: string, bash, variables

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to remove a defined pattern both at the beginning of a variable and at the end. I know I have to use `#` and `%` but I don't know the correct syntax.

In this case, I want to remove `http://` at the beginning, and `/score/` at the end of the variable `$line` which is read from `file.txt`.

Comment: What kind of pattern? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: yes, in this case: http:// at the beginning, and /score/ at the end. The $line is read from a file.txt

Comment: What you are looking for is parameter expansion, specifically to your case the `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` near the end of [this section of Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, you can't nest `${var%}`/`${var#}` operations, so you'll have to use temporary variable.

Like here:

```
var="http://whatever/score/"
temp_var="${var#http://}"
echo "${temp_var%/score/}"
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions with (for example) sed:

```
some_variable="$( echo "$var" | sed -e 's#^http://##; s#/score/$##' )"
```

Comment: I'm way more familiar with regular expressions. This is interesting. I know sed a bit. The question is, how to use the output produced by sed to use it in another command. Let's say to start a script. ./script.sh $variablemodifiedbysed

Comment: Updated the answer to show that the output of sed can be stored in variable, for reuse.

Comment: This finally works like a charm. I've been spending two hours figuring this out. I'm sure the others work as well, but again, I like using regular expressions. Thanks man !

Comment: Why use sed when bash has regular expression matching built-in?

Comment: what are these called and how do I learn more about such hacks in bash string manip?

Answer (score 16):

```
$ var='https://www.google.com/keep/score'
$ var=${var#*//} #removes stuff upto // from begining
$ var=${var%/*} #removes stuff from / all the way to end
$ echo $var
www.google.com/keep
```

Comment: Use more "quotes"   > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments>    
<http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>    
[when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 5):

You have to do it in 2 steps :

```
$ string="fooSTUFFfoo"
$ string="${string%foo}"
$ string="${string#foo}"
$ echo "$string"
STUFF
```

Comment: In my case, the string may or may not start with 'boo' or 'foo' and if it starts with any of them how could I implement an OR into the parsing to remove "boo" OR "foo" from beginning of a string?

Answer (score 3):

There IS a way to do it one step using only built-in bash functionality (no running external programs such as `sed`) -- with `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
url=http://whatever/score/
re='https?://(.*)/score/'
[[ $url =~ $re ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This matches against the regular expression on the right-hand side of the `=~` test, and puts the groups into the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

---

That said, it's more conventional to use two PE expressions and a temporary variable:

```
shopt -s extglob
url=http://whatever/score/
val=${url#http?(s)://}; val=${val%/score/}
printf '%s\n' "$val"
```

...in the above example, the `extglob` option is used to allow the shell to recognized "extglobs" -- bash's extensions to glob syntax (making glob-style patterns similar in power to regular expressions), among which `?(foo)` means that `foo` is optional.

---

By the way, I'm using `printf` rather than `echo` in these examples because many of `echo`'s behaviors are implementation-defined -- for instance, consider the case where the variable's contents are `-e` or `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
export x='https://www.google.com/keep/score';
var=$(perl -e 'if ( $ENV{x} =~ /(https:\/\/)(.+)(\/score)/ ) { print qq($2);}')
```