# How to perform a string replacement on a path in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to remove the path prefix.  Here is a small example showing just the issue.

**Makefile**

```
dist_directory = ./dist

default: build

build: $(patsubst %.md, $(dist_directory)/%.html, $(wildcard *.md))

$(dist_directory)/%.html: %.md
    @echo start
    @echo $@
    @echo ${$@//$(dist_directory)/}
    @echo end
```

Create a file: `touch stuff.md`

Then build: `make`

The output is:

```
start
dist/stuff.html

end
```

The expected output is:

```
start
dist/stuff.html
/stuff.html
end
```

There are similar posts on Stack Exchange. However, they have not worked for me in a Makefile for some reason. I'm probably doing something wrong.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311758/remove-specific-word-in-variable

[Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash)

[Remove substring matching pattern both in the beginning and the end of the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129050/remove-substring-matching-pattern-both-in-the-beginning-and-the-end-of-the-varia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues here.  The most fundamental one is that if you want to use shell variables you have to escape the dollar sign so that make doesn't interpret it.  And, you can only use shell variable substitutions on shell variables, while `$@` is a make variable, so you need:

```
@foo='$@' ; echo $${foo//$(dist_directory)/}
```

The more subtle one is that make always uses `/bin/sh` (POSIX standard shell) when it invokes recipes, and the above syntax is specific to bash.  One way around that would be to explicitly set `SHELL := /bin/bash` in your makefile to force make to use bash.  Luckily that is not necessary because POSIX sh can also do this, as mentioned by Reda in another answer:

```
@foo='$@' ; echo $${@##*/}
```

But even more, you don't need *any* of this because make sets the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$*` to the part of the target that matches the stem (the `%`):

```
@echo $*.html
```

It also sets `$(@F)` to the filename part of the `$@` variable:

```
@echo $(@F)
```

**ETA**

If you want to do something very similar to your shell variable expansion using GNU make you can use:

```
@echo $(patsubst $(dist_directory)/%,%,$@)
```

Comment: Re: $(@F) -- some of my real files are in subdirectories